# CSV file parsing to a list, make list public to parse against SQL table

Tags: c#, sql-server, webforms

Parsed a csv file to a list in a webapp form.

How do I make the list public so that I can call it and use it in other classes? I essentially need to parse through the data in the list against data in a SQL table.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void UploadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (FileUpload.HasFile)
        {

            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload.FileName);

            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["temp_dir"].ToString().Trim() + filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            { 
                using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    List<string[]> members = new List<string[]>();
                    int j = 0;

                    while (!read.EndOfStream)
                    {

                        string line = read.ReadLine();
                        string[] values = line.Split(',');

                        if(j==0)
                        {
                            j++;
                            continue;
                        }

                        long nbr = Convert.ToInt64(values[0]);
                        int lnbr = Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
                        int value = Convert.ToInt32(values[2]);
                        members.Add(values);
```

Comment: On a side note, CSV files can contain embedded commas that are enclosed in quotes, which your code doesn't handle. For an example of more comprehensive parsing, see the article [Reading and Writing CSV Files in C#](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/files/reading-and-writing-csv-files-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to check against SQL at the same time, you just need to move your `List` declaration up a little bit. Then after you parse the CSV, start your SQL code.

```
protected void UploadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string[]> members = new List<string[]>();

    /* parse upload file */

    /* check against SQL table */
```